# Using Google App Engine with own Subdomain

Tags: php, google-app-engine, subdomain

I have created a website which is hosted on Google App Engine, let's say under the url `test.appspot.com`.

Now I bought my own domain `test.com`. I added this domain in my Google App Engine Console, changed the DNS preferences of the subdomain `www` like Google said and can now access my page by via this url. So far, so good.

If I now click a link on my page it redirects me to `test.appspot.com/linkedPage.php` instead of to `test.com/linkedPage.php`.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this behaviour?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A little side note, that has little to do with the actual content of your question: if you would do two things: a) use less bold type-face in general and b) typewriter for code instead of bode type-face for inline code and files your questions would be more pleasent to the eye.

Comment: show us the link code

Comment: Are you using wordpress or another php application that automatically outputs the entire fqdn for hyperlinks?

Comment: No I am not using such an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior I wished works as default. I just made a mistake. I used an absolute path in my header statements. Changing them to relative fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your site will be visible on both `appspot.com` and `test.com`.

If you want only the `test.com` site to be functional you need to install 301 permanent redirect handlers for requests for `appspot.com` URLs. One approach for achieving this is illustrated in [this Q&A](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/90584).

If you want to keep both sites functional you need all your full path URLs to be dynamically built using the hostname obtained from the request being served. Not sure exactly how you can do this with PHP, tho (I'm a python user). Maybe something like [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) and/or [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query)?

Side note: if you keep both sites functional you'll notice you also need some extra care for SEO (due to duplicate content) - it can be addressed using canonical tags, for which again you'll need parsing the URL.